# Is there a windows sidebar widget that shows temperature from sensors inside the computer?

Tags: windows-vista, temperature, desktop-gadget, sidebar

Is there a windows vista sidebar widget that shows temperature from sensors inside the computer? I have found Speedfan. Would like something that runs as a sidebar widget.

Comment: is this question for Windows Vista? if not what operating system do you want this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpeedFan Temperature Monitor](http://widgets.yahoo.com/widgets/speedfan-temperature-monitor)

This is a Yahoo Widget - uses SpeedFan, a popular utility, to display your processor temperature simply and concisely.

[image]

---

Some Gadgets for Vista - [take a look](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsvista/tp/vistagadgetssu.htm)

Have a look at [this thread](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=218174), also for Vista you need Everest for it though

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are a few free ones if you want to use Yahoo Widgets, however I can not advise one over another. For Windows ones I have searched for you as I have not seen one and want one myself!

All that I could find for you (both by Googling and looking at the official gallery) was this:

http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=eae5b056-f64d-4e58-8b91-4de93edbc37a&bt=1

It ties into [Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/) (which is a good program) but I do not know if you can use this on the trial / if you do not activate and just leave running.

I am unable to locate a completely free option for you on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest giving [Samurize](http://www.samurize.com/modules/news/) a go.

The amount of community addons/widgets is so vast, it is ridiculous.

It can be customized by anyone, and I mean customized. Just look at the example [screen shots](http://www.samurize.com/modules/myalbum/) page.

It is a widget manager on steroids.

Oh, did I also mention that it is completely free?

Answer (score 0):

[Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/) can display gadgets on your desktop (though it's not free). It's pretty configurable; I have it configured to show this temperatures:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use coretemp, not a widget, but a taskbar app. Works great, and it's visible when my sidebar is blocked by my browser.